# Is it possible to output multiple values to different files from a single jq invocation?

Tags: shell, jq

I have a curl where I would like to extract two text to two different files, file1.crt and file2.key. currently configured this way by repeating curl.

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Vault-Token:{{ vault_token }}" https://fopp.com/v1/ACME/data/SSL/fopp.com | jq -r .data.data.crt > /files/nginx/ssl/file1.crt && 
curl -X GET -H "X-Vault-Token:{{ vault_token }}" https://fopp.com/v1/ACME/data/SSL/fopp.com | jq -r .data.data.key > /files/nginx/ssl/file2.key
```

I would like to know if with jq could handle to extract in just one command.

Comment: You can output multiple values, but you can't write them to different files.

Comment: Then you don't need them "on a single line" at all; you want to redirect the first output to one file and the second output to a different file, but you don't have any reason to care if those outputs are or are not on the same line.

Comment: @oguzismail, I'd very much prefer that it didn't, at least without an explicit "unsafe" toggle applied. Keeping the language constrained reduces the potential security impact of permitting untrusted users to provide queries.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry I was gonna comment on your answer. What kind of security issues we're talking about?

Comment: If queries can do file I/O, and you let untrusted users provide queries (say, as a way to let someone query a bunch of files across a pool of servers map/reduce style), then you're letting untrusted users do file I/O. I mean, the impact at that point should be pretty obvious. And at least in the past, it *used to be* that the only thing a malicious jq query could do was consume resources, which you could constrain just by setting a cap on amount of CPU a process is allowed to consume before getting killed.

Comment: @oguzismail, ...I've had just that kind of setup, with large pools of historical data distributed a bunch of servers that dev staff were allowed to query but not modify, at multiple employers at the past. Having the tools someone is using underpinning such infrastructure change to suddenly allow a query to perform modification rather than only collecting data is not without impact.

Comment: *letting untrusted users do file I/O* ugh, I wouldn't want that. You're right, it was not a good idea

Answer (score 2):

Not with only `jq` itself, but it's easy enough to combine with a bit of shell. If your values can't contain literal newlines, this can be as easy as:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Vault-Token:{{ vault_token }}" https://fopp.com/v1/ACME/data/SSL/fopp.com \
| jq -r '.data.data.crt, .data.data.key' \
| { IFS= read -r crt && printf '%s\n' "$crt" > /files/nginx/ssl/file1.crt;
    IFS= read -r key && printf '%s\n' "$key" > /files/nginx/ssl/file2.key; }
```

If the values *can* contain newlines, then you need to use a different separator. Consider:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Vault-Token:{{ vault_token }}" https://fopp.com/v1/ACME/data/SSL/fopp.com \
| jq -j '.data.data.crt, "\u0000", .data.data.key, "\u0000"' \
| { IFS= read -r -d '' crt && printf '%s\n' "$crt" > /files/nginx/ssl/file1.crt;
    IFS= read -r -d '' key && printf '%s\n' "$key" > /files/nginx/ssl/file2.key; }
```